# Missing postcard in Asterix & Obelix XXL 2

Tags: ps4, asterix-obelix-xxl-2

I have been following [a collectables guide](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/asterix-and-obelix-xxl-2-a/332029-100-all-collectibles-locations-postcards-diamond-helmet-challenges-etc.html) for Asterix & Obelix XXL 2 and can not find the second postcard for WCW. All other guides i have seen show this item in the same place. The place it is meant to occur is at the bottom of the Mario pipe:

[image]

But when I go there I see nothing:

I have the disc version of Asterix & Obelix XXL 2 on PS4, the version that says it is only for sale in Europe, Russia, and India. The latest patch (1.03) is installed. I have no idea if any of those facts is relevant or if my save is simply bugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all the guides seem to be incorrect and do not show postcards in the right order (they possibly all copied the same original guide), WCW #5 was in a different location (Swapped with WCW #3). Looking over the guide quite a few of the locations shown do not match the order they appear in the game's menu.